# Why a process used requests.get() via loop.run_in_executor() not run concurrently?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I use `loop.run_in_executor()` to call `requests.get()` but it runs without concurrence, while I comment that line and leave it only to call print in `loop.run_in_executor()`, the script run concurrently.

```py
import asyncio
import requests

async def get(name):
    loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(15):
        loop.run_in_executor(None,requests.get,'https://www.google.com',
                dict(proxies={'http':'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080','https':'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'}))
        loop.run_in_executor(None,print,f'{name} thread {i}th get')

async def main():
    await get('A')
    await get('B')
    await get('C')

loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

the output of the script is  ordered, like

```
A thread 0th get
A thread 1th get
...
A thread 14th get
B thread 0th get
B thread 1th get
...
B thread 14th get
C thread 0th get
C thread 1th get
...
```

However, the output is misordered after I comment line 7 and line 8,  the code:

```py
import asyncio
import requests

async def get(name):
    loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(15):
        #loop.run_in_executor(None,requests.get,'https://www.google.com',
                #dict(proxies={'http':'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080','https':'socks5://127.0.0.1:1080'}))
        loop.run_in_executor(None,print,f'{name} thread {i}th get')

async def main():
    await get('A')
    await get('B')
    await get('C')

loop=asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

the last several line of the output is like

```
...
C thread 5th get
C thread 0th get
C thread 13th get
B thread 12th get
C thread 2th get
C thread 6th get
C thread 10th get
```

Why the origin version run without concurrence?

Comment: Do you mind showing exactly how it looks like when you comment it?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I meant if you can add the code with the lines commented, having a way to reproduce the problem can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You misunderstood the execution logic, here is an another simpler example, but the logic is same, hope can help you. My english is not good, the code can express better than me.

```py
import asyncio
import random
import time


def sleep_print(a):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 300) / 100)
    print(a)


async def get(name):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    for i in range(4):
        loop.run_in_executor(None, sleep_print, f"first sleep_print: {name} thread {i}th get\n")
        loop.run_in_executor(None, sleep_print, f"second sleep_print: {name} thread {i}th get\n")


async def main():
    await get("A")


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
start = time.time()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
print("cost:", time.time() - start)
```

My output:

```
cost: 0.0006608963012695312

second sleep_print: A thread 1th get

second sleep_print: A thread 3th get

first sleep_print: A thread 2th get

first sleep_print: A thread 1th get

first sleep_print: A thread 0th get

second sleep_print: A thread 2th get

first sleep_print: A thread 3th get

second sleep_print: A thread 0th get
```